# how to get circle on which clicked in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, ontouchlistener

I am creating a custom view by extending View, drawing some circles on canvas, now i want to know the circle or the index of circle on which user clicks, how can i handle this, i didn't find any Circle class, so i can have a list of Circles.
below is my code----

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();
    System.out.println("width : " + width + ", Height : " + height);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    float ballDiameter = width / ((COLUMN_COUNT > ROW_COUNT) ? COLUMN_COUNT : ROW_COUNT);
    float ballRadius = ballDiameter / 2;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++) {
        float cy = ballRadius + i * ballDiameter;
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_COUNT; j++) {
            int nextInt = random.nextInt();
            if (nextInt % 4 == 0) {
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            } else {
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            }
            float cx = ballRadius + j * ballDiameter;

            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, ballRadius, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing in Canvas. You're *drawing* a circle, not *creating* a circle object. You'll need to handle touches on your view, and then determine whether the touch is within a drawn circle -- meaning you'll need to keep track of the circles you draw as well.

Comment: i get x,y position where user clicks, but how to get circle based on x,y position, is there any library method to get it ???

Comment: I see you didn't read my comment. Please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Example

```
float touchx;
float touchy;
float ballDiameter = width / ((COLUMN_COUNT > ROW_COUNT) ? COLUMN_COUNT : ROW_COUNT);
float ballRadius = ballDiameter / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++) {
    float cy = ballRadius + i * ballDiameter;
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_COUNT; j++) {
        float cx = ballRadius + j * ballDiameter;

       if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(touchx - cx, 2) + Math.pow(touchy- cy, 2))<ballRadius){

           //CIRCLE cx,cy was touched
       }

    }
}
```